# Find Ann(2), Ann(6) and Ann(5) in Z12 and What is Ann(m) $\forall m\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring with identity and let $a ∈ R$ and define $$\operatorname{Ann}(a) :=
\{x ∈ R \mid ax = 0\}$$
I have proved that this is a subring and an Ideal, but I am not sure how to find $\operatorname{Ann}(2)$, $\operatorname{Ann}(6)$, and $\operatorname{Ann}(5)$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{12}$. What I was thinking is that $\operatorname{Ann}(2)=2x=0$. So I just plugged in all the numbers in $\Bbb{Z}_{12}$ to $x$ and $\mod 12$. Not sure if this is correct. For example, I did
$$2(1)=2\mod 12=2$$ and $$2(2)=4\mod 12=4$$

Comment: $Ann(a)$ is a set not a value, but you have the right idea. For $Ann(2)$ just take each $x\in\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ and multiply it by $2$. If you get $0$ then that $x$ is in $Ann(2)$. If you get something nonzero then it is not in $Ann(2)$.

Comment: Alright, so I did do them and was not sure. So Ann(2)={0,6}?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Thank you for confirming, but I am not sure how the same thing works for the Z since it is not finite.

Comment: Let $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ be nonzero and suppose $xm = 0$. What can you say about $x$? How does this differ if $m=0$?

Comment: I am not sure how to go with it but I am thinking that the Ann(m) = {0} since Z is an infinite set.

Comment: It’s not because $\Bbb Z$ is infinite, it’s because it’s an integral domain.

Comment: I forgot about that! Now it makes sense. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: I think you've digested the problem statement somewhat, so I won't vote to close.  However the terminology that $\operatorname{Ann}(a)$ is a *subring* of $R$ ("a commutative ring with identity") is not as apt as saying it is an ideal.  Why?  Because it cannot share the identity element of $R$.